# how can I handle built-in intents in alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

intents like "next, previous, more.." the required built-in intents in my model, how exactly can i handle them in my code? i know i'm supposed to delegate but i can't figure out how to do that exactly. Please note, this is NOT a multi-turn dialog, so dialog state is always null !

```
SpeechletResponse speechletResp = new SpeechletResponse();

DelegateDirective dd = new DelegateDirective();
List<Directive> directiveList = new ArrayList<>();
directiveList.add(dd);
speechletResp.setDirectives(directiveList);
speechletResp.setNullableShouldEndSession(null);

return speechletResp;
```

sometimes the code returns an error and sometimes the intent executes sucessfullly !!!

I don't understand what's happening, no msgs are showing up on my cloud watch!

Answer (score 0):

They can be handled similarly as the other intents. So, I am posting a nodejs example which you can easily resemble in java too. You have to add **AMAZON** ahead of the built-in Intent.

```
"SampleIntent": function() {
    console.log('ArtistSearchIntent HelpIntent');
    this.emit(":ask", "Know more about on google.com . Good 
    Bye!!", "Know more about on google.com . Good Bye!!");
}
"AMAZON.StopIntent": function() {
    console.log('ArtistSearchIntent StopIntent');
    this.emit(":tell", "Know more about on google.com. Good 
     Bye!!");
},
"AMAZON.CancelIntent": function() {
    console.log('ArtistSearchIntent CancelIntent');
    this.emit(":tell", "Know more about on google.com. Good 
    Bye!!");
},
"AMAZON.HelpIntent": function() {
    console.log('ArtistSearchIntent HelpIntent');
    this.emit(":ask", "Know more about on google.com . Good 
    Bye!!", "Know more about on google.com . Good Bye!!");
}
```

Comment: From what I understand in the documentation all built-in intents for the Echo Show can be handled by the Delegate Directive EXCEPT:

1.  AMAZON.PreviousIntent
2.  AMAZON.NextIntent

these are the two intents i'm specifically having trouble handing. How do I tell alexa to return to the previous screen in my code or to show more items when displaying a Template?

Comment: @Acidburn73 I think you have to use state management for moving from one screen to another with the states intact.